# Federate grafana with apache2 + mod_auth_mellon to have SSO with SAML

Tags: apache, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, grafana

Trying to implement SSO ( Single SIgn On ) with Okta as IdP and I followed the next steps:

1. Install apache2 + mod_auth_mellon
2. Install grafana on the same host
3. Enable required apache2 modules like headers, authzn_core &
   authz_user and so on…
4. Generate metadata & configure mod_auth_mellon
5. Configure Grafana.

My Apache cfg:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
<Location />
    MellonEnable "info"
    MellonSPPrivateKeyFile /etc/apache2/mellon/urn_grafana.key
    MellonSPCertFile /etc/apache2/mellon/urn_grafana.cert
    MellonSPMetadataFile /etc/apache2/mellon/urn_grafana.xml
    MellonIdPMetadataFile /etc/apache2/mellon/idp-metadata.xml
    MellonEndpointPath /grafana
</Location>
    MellonPostDirectory "/var/cache/mod_auth_mellon_postdata"
    ProxyPass /grafana http://127.0.0.1:3000
    ProxyPassReverse /grafana http://127.0.0.1:3000
<Location /grafana>
    MellonEnable "auth"
    MellonPostReplay On
    MellonSamlResponseDump On
    MellonUser "NAME_ID"
    ProxyPassInterpolateEnv On
    RequestHeader set X-WEBAUTH-USER "%{MELLON_username}e"
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

My grafana cfg:

```
...
...
    [auth.proxy]
    enabled = true
    header_name = X-WEBAUTH-USER
    header_property = email
    auto_sign_up = true
...
...
```

I’ve been following the official documentation (github,com/UNINETT/mod_auth_mellon/wiki/GenericSetup) but looks like I’m doing something wrong.

The point is: It works partially, I mean:

When I try to access to http://X.X.X.X/grafana I’m redirected to Okta’s page to authenticate, then I’m redirected again to grafana http://X.X.X.X:3000/login but I recieve this:

```
[{"fieldNames":["User"],"classification":"RequiredError","message":"Required"},{"fieldNames":["Password"],"classification":"RequiredError","message":"Required"}]
```

Some tip? It looks like Grafana doesn’t recieve any parameter as username or passwd.
Trying to debug what parameters I recieve from Okta I didn’t figure out how to use the PHP code to print the headers.
I tried to use firefox SAMl tracer to debug this but no success…
Also looks like I’m not recieving any additional headers from Okta so I’m a little bit stuck here…

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE:** 
I tried to configure everything from 0 again and now with this config it works but the username is (null), so same behavior as before but now does the login into grafana. Actually it logs in even without authenticate to Okta! :o

Apache cfg:

```
LoadModule auth_mellon_module modules/mod_auth_mellon.so

RequestHeader set X-WEBAUTH-USER "%{MELLON_username}e"
ServerName grafana.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.aws
ProxyPassInterpolateEnv On
ProxyPass /login/saml !
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
ProxyRequests Off
<Location /login>
        MellonEnable "auth"
        #MellonSecureCookie Off
        MellonMergeEnvVars On
        MellonCookieDomain grafana.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.aws
        MellonCookiePath /
        MellonEndpointPath "/login/saml"
        MellonDefaultLoginPath "/"
        MellonNoCookieErrorPage "http://grafana.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.aws/no_cookie.html"
        MellonSPentityId "http://grafana.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.aws"
        MellonSPPrivateKeyFile /etc/httpd/mellon/http_grafana.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.aws_3000.key
        MellonSPCertFile /etc/httpd/mellon/http_grafana.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.aws_3000.cert
        MellonIdPMetadataFile /etc/httpd/mellon/idp-metadata.xml
        MellonAuthnContextClassRef "urn:federation:authentication:windows"
        MellonAuthnContextClassRef "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport"
</Location>
```

Grafana cfg:

```
...
...
[auth.proxy]
enabled = true
header_name = X-WEBAUTH-USER
header_property = username
header_email_name = X-WEBAUTH-EMAIL
header_email_property = email
header_full_name = X-WEBAUTH-NAME
header_full_property = fullname
auto_sign_up = true
...
...
```

Maybe related to this issue: github,com/grafana/grafana/issues/7049
but I'm surprised that nobody posted a howto about how to config grafana with mod_auth_mellon in order to have SSO with SAML.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the `env=MELLON_username`, that worked for me.

```
RequestHeader set X-WEBAUTH-USER %{MELLON_user}e env=MELLON_user
RequestHeader set X-WEBAUTH-USER %{MELLON_email}e env=MELLON_email
RequestHeader set X-WEBAUTH-USER %{MELLON_username}e env=MELLON_username
```

Comment: Please add more information on how and where to add the additional configurations or pass the parameters. would be helpful to triage and try out easily.