# SAML with mod_auth_mellon

Tags: apache, saml

I've configured apache to make SAML auth for Grafana but the "X-WEBAUTH-USER" is not transfered to the header :

```
nc -l -p 9119
POST /grafana/ HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:9119
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://samlidp.example.com/
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Origin: https://samlidp.example.ch
DNT: 1
Cookie: mellon-cookie=cookietest
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
X-WEBAUTH-USER: (null)
```

Here is my config :

```
ServerName servername.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@servername.com
ServerAlias servername.com

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"


# Logs and diagnotic
LogLevel debug

SSLEngine on
SSLProxyEngine On
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.key

#SSLv2 and v3 are bad
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!SSLv2:!ADH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!NULL

ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9119/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9119/



    <Location />
            Require valid-user
            AuthType "Mellon"
            MellonEnable "auth"
            MellonDecoder "none"
            MellonVariable "cookie"
            MellonSecureCookie On
            MellonUser "NAME_ID"
            MellonSetEnv REMOTE_USER MELLON_NAME_ID
            MellonSetEnv "REMOTE_MAIL" "email"
            MellonEndpointPath "/endpoint"
            MellonDefaultLoginPath "/"
            MellonSessionLength 300

            # Mellon requires a cert, regardless if it's actually being used.
            MellonSPPrivateKeyFile /etc/apache2/mellon/urn_grafana.key
            MellonSPCertFile /etc/apache2/mellon/urn_grafana.cert
            MellonSPMetadataFile /etc/apache2/mellon/urn_grafana.xml

            #MellonSPPrivateKeyFile /etc/apache2/mellon/urn_keycloak.key
            #MellonSPCertFile /etc/apache2/mellon/urn_keycloak.cert
            #MellonSPMetadataFile /etc/apache2/mellon/urn_keycloak.xml


            # Make sure to copy your IdP metadata here
            MellonIdPMetadataFile /etc/apache2/mellon/idp-persistent.xml
            #MellonIdPMetadataFile /etc/apache2/mellon/idp-keycloak.xml
            MellonSamlResponseDump On
            MellonSessionDump On
            RequestHeader set X-WEBAUTH-USER "%{REMOTE_USER}e"
            RequestHeader set X-MAIL "%{REMOTE_MAIL}e"
    </Location>

    <Location /grafana/>
            MellonEnable "off"
            Order Deny,Allow
            Allow from all
            Satisfy Any
    </Location>
```

Any ideas ? 
I've tried this : [Federate grafana with apache2 + mod_auth_mellon to have SSO with SAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45611089/federate-grafana-with-apache2-mod-auth-mellon-to-have-sso-with-saml) but in that case the X-WEBAUTH-USER is not even in the header.

Comment: Why you can't use OIDC with https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/auth/generic-oauth/?

Comment: @JanGaraj we are using SAML SSO for other applications, so it's a company choice to use SAML.

Comment: IMHO your SSO will still be working even you combine OIDC/SAML Keycloak clients. If you really needs SAML, then I will recommend Apache + Shibboleth.

Comment: @JanGaraj I will have a look at it but we don't use Keycloak. It's a security solution (not opensource). I will definetely have a look at Shibboleth, thanks

Comment: @JanGaraj Have you configure a Shibboleth before ? 
I am getting the error : 
`CRIT Shibboleth.Application : error building MetadataProvider: XML configuration resource missing url/path attributes and has no inline content`

I configured it with :
`<MetadataProvider type="XML" file="idp.xml"/>`

Thanks

Comment: Wrong local IDP metadata file? IMHO you can use URL directly `<MetadataProvider type="XML" validate="true" url="<URL TO IDP METADATA FILE>"  backingFilePath="idp-metadata.xml" maxRefreshDelay="7200">`

Comment: @JanGaraj : I put a new idp config file and this part now works.

The issue is now to display "grafana". 
My ACS URL is https://serviceurl.com/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST and I can get an answer from grafana but it is not reaching it with the propoer URL ( it's expecting the one I setted up in apache with the ProxyPass directive. Is there a way to forward it to /grafana instead of /Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST ?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, this is not a chat, where you can use me as a free support for all your issues. Please open new question with https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and wait if someone will help you.

Comment: @JanGaraj : sorry about that, I got it working, thanks for your advices.